# Adding comment resets question score on Area 51

Tags: bug, comments, area-51, down-votes

I was looking at my Area 51 proposal, [Driving](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/81871/driving), and noticed downvotes on some of my suggested questions. I left a comment under one of the downvoted questions and immediately the score reset to zero. Looking at my reputation, it still seems to register the downvote.

Someone else just added a "*test test test*" comment beneath my final downvoted question, and this also reset it to zero. So it's not just the question asker who can trigger this behaviour.

This doesn't appear to be serial downvote reversal, since [a commenter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246957/adding-comment-resets-question-score-on-area-51#comment809519_246957) has added a single downvote just now and a comment from me reset the score. In fact, based on the other comments below, we may have a general voting problem on Area 51 at the moment.

(Feel free to downvote some of my proposed questions if people would like to experiment).

Comment: It might have been the same person had downvoted most of your questions. Rightly or wrongly (probably the latter in most cases) the serial voting script will reverse sequential votes on Area 51 if the examples are all posted by the same person.

Comment: @PeterJ That wouldn't explain why the reputation wasn't adjusted nor why it requires a comment to trigger the reset. (Note: I don't care about the loss of rep, but it's an indicator that parts of the system still believe a downvote happened).

Comment: Most likely those were serial downvotes that have been reversed, however having very old codebase, Area51 reputation history won't show it. :/

Comment: I just downvoted "How do I bring a caravan under control if it begins to sway?" if you want to add a comment.

Comment: @PeterJ Adding a comment seems to have reset that too.

Comment: Removed the unjustified DV just now but saw before I did that it had gone back to zero even though my downvote button was still selected, bizarre!

Comment: @PeterJ Can you upvote a question and notify me? I'll see if adding a comment resets it downwards to zero.

Comment: Just did that on "Am I allowed to "undertake" when driving in Germany?"

Comment: @PeterJ Did you notice someone else comment? The score is at zero, but I'm not sure what caused it.

Comment: Not sure either, I didn't notice anything but am a bit shy of the 1000 rep to view the up and downvote counts. I've left my upvote there but I guess it's possible someone meanwhile had downvoted it.

Comment: I did remove my downvote.. didn't comment and after refreshing the "undertake" question was at 0 again (even though it switched to +1 when removing the downvote). This seems to be a "general" votes problem on a51...

Comment: @PeterJ http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep

Comment: @Scimonster doesn't seem to work on Area 51. Must be something to do with the older code base.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a comment doesn't change the actual votes. It does change the display of the net score. So adding a comment to a question that was at 0/-2 (net -2) left it at 0/-2, but the displayed net score went to zero. Once I refreshed the screen, the correct -2 net score was displayed. So perhaps this is a problem with the javascript that's updating the page once the comment has been posted.

Upon further refreshes, sometimes the question shows its true negative net score, and sometimes it shows zero.

So conceivably, this could be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), where what's being tested is whether the displayed score affects people's voting patterns.

Or it's caching. (When in doubt, blame caching. Or internationalisation. Or a combination of the two.)

Comment: I think we should blame キャッシュ